# CSS. Sizing div based on device screen width (not the window)

Tags: css

I want to set the element width equal to (device screen width) / 4.
Viewport width and height (vw, vh) are not suitable for this.
Can I do this with CSS only?

I'm going to ad media rule like this:

```
@media (min-width: 550px) {
    .poster {
        width: 25%;     /* here I want to set 25% of screen width */
        height: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here. Also if you dont want static values for the width element, you need JavaScript for this to calculate the value and set it to the element.

Comment: I don't think so.  Only the client will know what size the screen is.  I think you'll need to include some JavaScript.

Comment: Why isnt `width: 25vw` not suitable for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you take a good look at this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Basically use percentages (25% for 1/4 of the device screen)

Comment: As I remember, % is related to the parent element, not to the screen size.
However, thanks for the link.